# Json: JSONException: No value for UserNm

Tags: android, json, getstring

I have a problem with the extraction of data from a JSON file that I receive from a PHP file

This is the filecontents of the JSON file I `get`:

> {"success":1,"message":"Data of the Person",
>   "0":{"Name":"Marco","Surname":"Rossi","Age":"32"}}

I tried to use the getString function but it gives me the error JSONException: No value for lane_prodoct

This is an excerpt of the function I use to recover my data:

```js
success = jObj.getString("success");
UserNm = jObj.getString("Name");
UserSrm = jObj.getString("Surname");
UserAge= jObj.getString("Age");
```

Comment: Not a valid JSON string. You are missing `}` at the end.

Comment: I know I made a mistake when I corrected him

Comment: Your error message does not match your JSON string at all. Please really provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON

```
{"success":1,"message":"Data of the Person", "0":{"Name":"Marco","Surname":"Rossi","Age":"32"}
```

here the last `}` is missing. 
It should be like

```
{"success":1,"message":"Data of the Person", "0":{"Name":"Marco","Surname":"Rossi","Age":"32"}}
```

Comment: The JSON I receive is formatted as you say !! in fact I corrected the post, What I do not understand is because the value of "success" I can extract it while others are not

Comment: You need to construct `"0":{"Name":"Marco","Surname":"Rossi","Age":"32"}`as a json object.From that you need to query for `Name`

Comment: Ok !! could you give me some indication before I tried creating another Json file and inserting the value "0" inside but it does not go: 'JSONObject jObj1 = jObj. [' 0 ']:'

Comment: do like `JSONObject j1=jObj.getJSONObject("0");` now from j1 get the Name like `j1.getString("Name")`

Comment: Thanks for your help